# What unit of time is the AE.Net.Mail c# library .ServerTimeout measered in?

Tags: c#, email

In the AE.Net.Mail c# library, when I get the imapclient object, I get as .ServerTimeout property, which accepts an integer for time, but doesn't specify what kind it is. Does anyone know if it's in seconds, or milliseconds or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in milliseconds. As it used in method [`Wait`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270644(v=vs.110).aspx) of `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` class. Here is the [source line](https://github.com/andyedinborough/aenetmail/blob/d8ad4fa049394f3382cafe6082da5c310eb60598/ImapClient.cs#L184).